# How to remove extra outage of StackPane size?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, java-8

Please view the attached image , inside StackPane number "1" , i added an image which called "Icon" , and i changed its Y Position to be at the top of StackPane , but what happened that the extra of Image Icon didn't be hidden automatically although of  setting max size to the StackPane ,

so what i want to do is to hide the outage of StackPane , as shown in StackPane number "2" ,

Notice : i made StackPane number "2" using photoshop , to explain what i mean

Thank you ,

[image]

Comment: Please include valid code to reproduce it. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you explain here is a feature of the JavaFX SceneGraph: A Child node can be drawn outside of the bounds of it's parent. I you want to cut the edges you need to use the setClip(...) method of the Node class. A example can be found here: http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/06/22/masking-in-javafx-2-0/